# select data from two table using month and year only in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
Entered-month  Entered-year  Amount
-------------------------------------
01             2013        3000
02             2013        4000
.               .           .
.               .           .
.               .           .
01             2014        2000
```

My table is like this
I have to take data Amounts between Two dates
For ex  01/11/2011  To 03/01/2014

Comment: `select data from two table` but i see only one ??

Comment: Make the field as date or datetime. Then it would be easy to perform date operations, and if you wanna do select you can select the date, month, etc as like whatever you want....

Comment: i cant chage the field as datetime or date beacause its a on a wrking model,,,, Have to get report,,,, Between two dates from this table

Comment: if i am taking the results between two years i am geting the result, bt i have to consider dates also,,,,

Comment: sory Have to cosider Year and Monhs

Comment: Ex:: 01/12/2013  to 05/01/2014   I had values

Answer (score 0):

Use MySQL functions `STR_TO_DATE` and `CONCAT` to put your month and year fields together as a date.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

```
select Amount
from tbl1
where STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(tbl1.Entered-month,'-',tbl1.Entered-year),'%m-%Y') >= [start date] 
    and STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(tbl1.Entered-month,'-',tbl1.Entered-year),'%m-%Y') <= [end date]
```

OR

```
select Amount
from tbl1
where STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(tbl1.Entered-month,'-',tbl1.Entered-year),'%m-%Y') 
    between [start date] and [end date]
```

Make sure `[start date]` and `[end date]` are in the correct date format when passed into the query.  Use `STR_TO_DATE` on those parameters if they are string parameters.

```
select Amount
from tbl1
where STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(tbl1.Entered-month,'-',tbl1.Entered-year),'%m-%Y') 
    between STR_TO_DATE(startDate,'%Y-%m-%d') and STR_TO_DATE(endDate,'%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: SQL Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[fromdate]  and STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(e.kpimonth,'-',e.kpiyear),'%m-%Y') <= [todate' at line 68

Comment: insert into tmpempkpiscore(kpiscoreid,kpitarget,kpiactual,kpimonth,kpiyear,empid,resscoreid,resid) select e.kpiscoreid,e.kpitarget,e.kpiactual,e.kpimonth,e.kpiyear,e.empid,s.resscoreid,s.resid from pepemployeescoredetails as e inner join pepkpiscore as s where e.kpiscoreid=s.kpiscoreid and STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(e.kpimonth,'-',e.kpiyear),'%m-%Y') >= [fromdate]  and STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(e.kpimonth,'-',e.kpiyear),'%m-%Y') <= [todate] ;

Comment: Are you passing valid date parameters into `[fromdate]` and `[todate]`?  Are you using stored procedures?  http://www.mysqltutorial.org/stored-procedures-parameters.aspx

Comment: yep its in a MySQL stored procedure

Comment: string date1 = Radfromdate.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            string date2 = RadDtodate.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");



    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "departmentwiseoverdueanalysis";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fromdate", date1);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@todate", date2);

Comment: Convert `[fromdate]` and `[todate]` to dates in the statement.  They look like strings.  `STR_TO_DATE(fromdate,'%Y-%m-%d')`  Check formatting.

Comment: its OK i can Pass parameters as date, But First of all i have to create the Procedure rit?? while creating Procedure its showing that error

Comment: SQL Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[fromdate] and STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(e.kpimonth,'-',e.kpiyear),'%m-%Y') <=

Comment: NAME       TYPE      SCOPE
==========================
Fromdate   datetime   int
Todate     datetime   int            these are my parameters in this procedure

Comment: Did you get it to work?  Can you just run a simple select to see if the `STR_TO_DATE` and `CONCAT` are working?  Run this select and see if it returns the dates    `select STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(e.kpimonth,'-',e.kpiyear),'%m-%Y') from pepemployeescoredetails as e inner join pepkpiscore as s where e.kpiscoreid=s.kpiscoreid`

Comment: i jst added a new temporary field to My sql table, Which s "KpiMonthYear"   Updated This field as STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(e.kpimonth,'-',e.kpiyear),'%m-%Y')              THen i passed the from and to dates to the procedure and i splt those dates as  from mnth,from yearand tomonth and toyear,, Then i changed those as Like(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(e.kpimonth,'-',e.kpiyear),'%m-%Y'))        then i wrote a query to Select data, Now its Working,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Comment: Did my answer to use `STR_TO_DATE` and `CONCAT` help?

Comment: Ok thanks.  If you think it helped solve your question, mark as answer or up vote so others with the same question can see it easier.